# How can I add an XSL stylesheet inside an XML file with C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a C# console application that runs and adds the following to the a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <qf:VisualTemplate xmlns:qf="http://www.Qnomy.com/Templates" version="1.0" description="test doc">
      <qf:Styles />
      <qf:Parameters />
      <qf:SampleData />
      <qf:Design />
    </qf:VisualTemplate>
```

It uses this bit of code to do that:

```
        var doc = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement(ns + "VisualTemplate",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "qf", url),
                new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                new XAttribute("description", "test doc"),
                    new XElement(ns + "Styles"),
                    new XElement(ns + "Parameters"),
                    new XElement(ns + "SampleData"),
                     new XElement(ns + "Design")
            )
        );
```

I need to also add an embedded xsl stylesheet in between the qf:Design node, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<qf:VisualTemplate xmlns:qf="http://www.Qnomy.com/Templates" version="1.0" description="test doc">
  <qf:Styles />
  <qf:Parameters />
  <qf:SampleData />
  <qf:Design>
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
       </xsl:stylesheet>
  </qf:Design>
</qf:VisualTemplate>
```

I have tried doing it the same way as i created the xml but i cant use xsl as the namespace:

```
    var url2 = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";

    var ns2 = XNamespace.Get(url2);

    var d = doc.Descendants(ns + "Design").First();

    d.AddBeforeSelf(new XComment("Place your HTML elements here"));
    d.Add(
        new XElement(ns + "Design",
            new XElement(ns2 + "stylesheet",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsl", ""),
                new XAttribute("version", "1.0")
            )
        )
    );
```

Is there any way i can add the xsl stylesheet with C# in the same way as i have done the XML elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your expected output XML, the `xsl` prefix should've been bound to `"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`, not to empty string :

```
.....
new XElement(ns2 + "stylesheet",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"),
    new XAttribute("version", "1.0")
)
.....
```